# in what event the submit button enable should be written if text boxes are filled, for VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

my question is in what event the submit button enable should be written if text boxes are filled, for VBA

for example im talking about the Private sub userform initialize()

i had created a userform where i used 2 frames. while the macro runs it initialize the first frame and user logins using that form to go the next form which is in the other frame.

in this second frame form i have 3 text box fields. only if the user inputs all the three text box then the command button should be enabled. im now stuck with in which event this code should be written.

Thank you

Comment: you could have the code associated with the command button verify the 3 text box fields are completed and then allow the program to continue otherwise end execution.

Comment: thanks i haven't thought of that.. thank you i will try

Answer (score 1):

assuming the button is named after "CommandButton1" and the three textboxes are name after "TextBox1", "TextBox1" and "TextBox3", then in the Userform code pane add the following:

- In `UserForm_Initialize` place:

  ```
  Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = False
  ```
- add Change event handler for all those three textboxes

  ```
  Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
      checkEnableButton
  End Sub

  Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
      checkEnableButton
  End Sub

  Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
      checkEnableButton
  End Sub
  ```
- finally add the following:

  ```
  Sub checkEnableButton()
      Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = Me.TextBox1.Value <> "" And Me.TextBox2.Value <> "" And Me.TextBox3.Value <> ""
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it possible to keep the button disabled if the user tries to enter just spaces in the text box fields?